# Where is KNode in Kubuntu 15.10 "Wily"?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, kde5

I just installed Kubuntu 15.10 "Wily Werewolf" and found that it seems to be missing KNode.

A Google search turned up the page http://packages.ubuntu.com/en/wily/knode and there is information about the package in Google's cache of this page, but the link now 404s.
In Kontact, there is no option for "Usenet", as it used to be in previous versions of Kubuntu.

Why has KNode been removed from Kubuntu and how can I get it back? Is there a replacement Usenet reader for KDE5?

Note that I am looking for a "real" Usenet client, not a binary downloader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, KNode has been removed as it was using old code and no one has volunteered to keep it up to date.

Thunderbird has support for usenet.

However, it was later re-added to the repositories and is now available for installed in Kubuntu 16.10.

Source:

http://www.aegiap.eu/kdeblog/2015/08/kdepim-5-0/